# "cannot find symbol" error w/ AudioTrack

Tags: java, android

Considering I've never written a line of Java before today, I'm sure I've missed something obvious. In any case, I'm working on an Android app that uses the AudioTrack class to play generated audio.

I'm importing everything I think I'm supposed to:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
```

Within my Activity class I have this function:

```
public AudioTrack toneToAudioTrack(byte samples[], int numSamples) {
    final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        sampleRate,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT,
        numSamples,
        AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC
    );

    audioTrack.write(samples, 0, numSamples);

    return audioTrack;
}
```

When I try to compile with ant, I get this:

> compile:
>       [javac] /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:384: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not
>   set, defaulting to
>   build.sysclasspath=last; set to false
>   for repeatable builds
>       [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/electrode/ditdah/bin/classes
>       [javac] /home/electrode/ditdah/src/org/n8fq/DitDah/DitDahActivity.java:38:
>   cannot find symbol
>       [javac] symbol  : constructor AudioTrack(int,double,int,int,int,int)
>       [javac] location: class android.media.AudioTrack
>       [javac]             audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
>       [javac]                          ^
>       [javac] 1 error
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:384: Compile failed; see the compiler error
>   output for details.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument to the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#AudioTrack%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) should be an int

```
final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    (int) sampleRate,
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT,
    numSamples,
    AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC
);
```